# Converting to utf-8 python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am using Ubuntu and python 3.4 to download data from wikipedia's api. I am saving the names and I saw that characters in different languages are not saved correctly.

For example: 日の火曜日 is saved as æ¥ã®ç«ææ¥.

I figured I may not be saving it in utf-8 so I changed my code to

```
fd = io.open("filename",'w',encoding='utf8')
fd.write(str(name.encode('utf-8'), 'utf-8'))
```

But I still get the same result.

The api I am using is [here](https://br.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allusers&format=xml&auprop=registration%7Ceditcount%7Cgroups&aulimit=500).

What I understand upto this point is that, utf-8 should be able to handle texts for all languages. Also the console in Ubuntu has utf-8 by default and it should print out the strings correctly if I run a command like `more`.

Comment: How are you getting the data into Python? Is this through `urlopen()`? I just used the `urlopen()` on your link and saved the output in a file and it's working fine.

Comment: Thank you. I am doing this:

`with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as url:
                s = url.read()`

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't simply your terminal that is interpreting it as a different encoding?

Comment: For example in my terminal if I do: `>>> u'日の火曜日'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
'æ\x97¥ã\x81®ç\x81«æ\x9b\x9cæ\x97¥'` see how the output contains the characters you see and some other bytes? Maybe in your case the other bytes are simply ignored/not shown.

Comment: If `name` is bytes, do `name.decode('utf-8')`, now you got text, you can write now. `fd.write(name.decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: How do I test that? 

I did echo $LANG and it was giving me en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Open the file in binary mode from python and see if the bytes contained are a correct utf-8 representation for those japanese/chinese characters?

Comment: `sys.stdout.encoding` has terminal encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my ssh client and it was displaying the strings incorrectly. The code was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the reponse code, get charset from the reponse and use it to decode. You can use `name.decode('utf-8')` or `str(name, 'utf-8')` to decode.

F.e.

```
resp = urlopen(url)
if resp.code == 200:
    with open('filename', 'w') as fd:
        fd.write(str(name, resp.info().get_content_charset()))
        #or fd.write(name.decode(resp.info().get_content_charset()))
```